# Tag [devtools] - cleanup or delete?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

[devtools](/questions/tagged/devtools) (63 questions) seems very meta-ish. If it was up to me I would delete the tag.

Should [devtools](/questions/tagged/devtools) undergo a cleanup or is it better to delete the tag?

Comment: It's not meta-ish imo. Retagging `[devtools][google-chrome]` to `[google-chrome-devtools]` would not hurt though.

Comment: If [devtools] is not meta-ish then what is. @Rob I would like you to show me _a question_ please, in which [devtools] was well chosen as tag.

Comment: Actually, after filtering all webkit-devtools related questions, there are barely any questions left on which "devtools" is significant. [`[tools]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tools) is also included as a part of the Cleanup. "Devtools" is less generic than "tools", but still not a useful tag, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

A quick browse-through indicates that [devtools](/questions/tagged/devtools) indicates:

- Generic development tool requests for languages or techniques
- Chrome devtools
- R devtools
- Android devtools
- Indellij devtools
- iPhone devtools
- Using emacs with Erlang
- Microsoft devtools/Visual Studio
- Windows clipboard viewing for development
- Java devtools
- Git for development

, and more.

This seems to me like the perfect example of a meta-tag.  Half the problem is that there's no tag wiki, so thus no concensus on what belongs there.  With only 64 questions tagged, it's not clear that a more narrowly defined topic area would have enough questions to merit a tag.  If the tag is defined broadly as "any tool for development," there's a conceptual problem, in that SO is a site to ask questions about code development.  Isn't everything a devtool in some sense?